# Changing gradient colors of an animated background

Tags: css

I have an animated gradient background, and I want to override the original color by applying an other class. When I apply this new class, the animation stops.

See the code below and try to add the `oc` class to the `div` to reproduce.

```css
.background {
    background: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        #eee9e5 20%,
        red 50%,
        #eee9e5 80%
    );
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 16px 0;
}

.oc {
  background: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        #eee9e5 20%,
        blue 50%,
        #eee9e5 80%
    ) !important;
}

.animated {
    animation: move 4s ease-in infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
```

```html
<div class="background animated" />
```

You can also see the code at https://codepen.io/Taskim/pen/KegLmJ.

Do you know any workaround to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the use of the `!important` on the `background` rule.

The `background` is a short-hand property that alters all the `background-*` properties.

So when you set `background: linear-gradient(...)!important` you override the `background-position` as well and setting it to default values that cannot be animated since they are more important.

Use `background-image: linear-gradient(...)` and it should work.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.animated').classList.toggle('oc');
})
```

```css
.background {
  background: linear-gradient( to right, #eee9e5 20%, red 50%, #eee9e5 80%);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 16px 0;
}

.oc {
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, #eee9e5 20%, blue 50%, #eee9e5 80%);
}

.animated {
  animation: move 4s ease-in infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="background animated"></div>
<button>toggle gradient</button>
```

---

Also keep in mind that you cannot self-close a `div` (*unless that is not real html but some template from a framework*)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am using jsx ;)